# Running a PHP script via Ajax, through a link?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, rating

I'm making a fairly simple rating system, and I've got a small problem. When you +1 rate something, I'm trying to run a PHP script which will connect to the database, download the value from it, +1 to that value, and UPDATE the value in the database again.

I don't think reloading the page for a continious rating system would be a very good idea :S

I'm wondering how I can toggle a PHP script with Ajax, so that when you Click an image of a + sign, it runs the PHP add 1 script, and the + button turns in to a tick. I'm crap at ajax, and I'd go for trying jQuery + $.ajax({}); but I've failed 73 attempts. haha.

Anyone willing to give me a hand writing an Ajax script? :DDD

Thanks! :)

Comment: show us your code,even if it fails

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you post your code attempts and be specific about what problems you're having you're more likely to get help.

Comment: Give some example code here. I don't think it is too difficult

Comment: It worked pretty well, I used watcher's code. :D I'd post the code attempt but it's way over the limit, haha :S

Answer (score 2):

If you want someone to click a link which will access your page, let's assume you have this marup:

```
<a class = 'plusOne' id = 'someIDForYourSQLTable'>+1</a>
```

The ID is what you are going to pass to your server script so you can update the appropriate row, generally speaking this should be a primary identifier (i.e. Key) for the record that you want to +1.

Here is the jQuery that will send the ajax request to the file: plusOne.php in the same directory as the current page:

```
$(function() {
    $(".plusOne").bind("click", function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            data: "v="+$(this).attr("id"),
            url: "plusOne.php",
            success: function(data) {
                // Whatever you want to do after the PHP Script returns.
            }
        });
    });
});
```

The request will send the a URL parameter 'v' which you can access in your PHP script from the `$_GET` super global array.

Comment: I cannot express my love for you! Haha, THANK YOU VERY. VERY MUCH!

Answer (score 1):

html

```
<img src="plusone.png" rel="some_unique_id" class="rate" />
```

javscript

```
$(".rate").click(function() {
   var elem = $(this);
   $.get('/rate.php?id=' + elem.attr('rel'), function() {
         elem.attr('src', 'checked.png').unbind('click');
   });
});
```

and in php

```
mysql_connect('localhost','db_user','pssword');
mysql_query('UPDATE database_name.table_name SET rating=rating+1 where id=' . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']));
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [xAjax](http://www.xajax-project.org/), a library to **expose PHP functions/method to client-side JavaScript**. [xAjax](http://www.xajax-project.org/) makes things very simple.

For example, you are able to perform several changes in the browser in parallel:

```
$objResponse = new xajaxResponse();
$objResponse->assign("myInput1","value",$DataFromDatabase);
$objResponse->assign("myInput1","style.color","red");
$objResponse->append("myDiv1","innerHTML",$DataFromDatabase2);
$objResponse->prepend("myDiv2","innerHTML",$DataFromDatabase3);
$objResponse->replace("myDiv3","innerHTML","xajax","<strong>xajax</strong>");
$objResponse->script("var x = prompt("Enter Your Name");");
return $objResponse;
```